# UIButton width not filling toolbar when run on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolbar with a button in it. In the storyboard everything looks fine. The problem is when I run it on the simulator it doesn't look the same as on the storyboard.

(Note: It won't even let me add constraints to the button.)

In storyboard:

[image]

In simulator:

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Bar button items do not size automatically, and the size you have set is for 4 inch and below device, because this is the default size in storyboards. However, you are running on an iPhone 6 simulator, thus the screen is wider, and the button does not fill the entire bar.

If you need to have the button fill the entire bar, you will have to do it in code, in `viewDidLayout`, changing the bar button item's `width` to that of the bar.

Comment: Can't I just add a constraint to it?

Comment: No, because bar button item is not a view.